# Why my spring gateway doesn't propagate token to resource server?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-cloud, gateway

I am playing a bit with spring authentications and I am trying to secure my microservice. I implemented my gateway to be authenticated with goole, and pass the access token to my game-config-service, there I want to fetch my authenicate user (name, email)

In my gateway:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}")
    private String googleClientId;
    @Value("${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}")
    private String googleClientSecret;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(CLIENT_NAME)
                .clientId(googleClientId)
                .clientSecret(googleClientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .scope(SCOPE.EMAIL.getValue(), SCOPE.PROFILE.getValue(), SCOPE.OPENID.getValue())
                .authorizationUri(AUTHORIZATION_URI)
                .tokenUri(TOKEN_URI)
                .userInfoUri(USER_INFO_URI)
                .clientName(CLIENT_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("game-config-service", r -> r.path("/api/v1/configuration/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.tokenRelay())
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9090/login/oauth2/code/google
            scope:
              - email
              - profile

  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: game-config-service
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/configuration/**


server:
  port: 9090
```

My game-configuration-service , Group controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/configuration/group")
public class GroupController {

    private final GroupService groupService;
    private final ModelMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public GroupController(GroupService groupService, ModelMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.groupService = groupService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Long createGroup(@Valid @RequestBody GroupApi group, @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2Authentication auth) {
        return groupService.createGroup(group);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<GroupApi> getAll(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2Authentication auth) {
        return groupService.getAll()
                .stream()
                .map(group -> mapper.map(group, GroupApi.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public long delete(@PathVariable("id") long playerId) {
        return groupService.delete(playerId);
    }
}
```

Now i am trying via the browser fetch all my groups via `http://localhost:9090/api/v1/configuration/group`
Google authenticaion window opens and I am login and its redirect me to `http://localhost:8081/login` page, why is that? how can I get to my route succesfully with my authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

The gateway filters [configuration I use](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) is (mind the trailing `=` with `TokenFilter=` and the `SaveSession` filter):

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - SaveSession
```

Note that it is likely that Google will provide with opaque access tokens (not JWTs), but not with an introspection endpoint for it. The audience of this tokens is likely to be limited to Google APIs. You'll probably have to use an authorization server of your own with "Login with Google" feature (a cloud service like Auth0, a Keycloak instance, something that you build yourself with `spring-authorization-server`, ...). This authorization server would deliver JWTs to be used by your own resource servers.